# Why do I get a ClassCastException using generics in this case?

Tags: java, generics

This is the code: A simple ceneric class and trying to assign an integer to `aa[0]`.

```
public class GenericTest<T> {
    T [] aa = (T[]) new Object[2];
    T bb;
    public GenericTest(T x, T y) {
        aa[0] = x; aa[1] = y;
        System.out.println(aa[0] + " " + aa[1]); //OK
    }
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        GenericTest<Integer> ll = new GenericTest<>(1,2);
        ll.bb = 1; // OK
        ll.aa[0] = 6; // ClassCastException from Object to Integer

    }
}
```

Comment: The actual error message is : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Intege`  It's having trouble converting the array `ll.aa` to type of `Integer[]`.  My guess is it's a corner case with the new type inference and might be a bug.

Comment: @markspace this is nothing new and not a bug.

Comment: I'm a little shocked that the compiler is actually inserting a cast on the left hand side of the assignment (as opposed to the right).  It's certainly counter-intuitive even if you know a bit about generics.  6 can be promoted to Integer which is assignable as an element for an Object[].  But the compiler insists on trying to cast the Object[] to type Integer[], which it clearly is not, and seems to cause a failure for no good reason.

Comment: For example, if I add the lines `Object[] oo = new Object[2];oo[0] = 6;` this compiles and runs fine.  Why should the generic version work differently?  The checks (cast) should go on the right side of the assignment, not the left.

Comment: @markspace "The checks (cast) should go on the right side of the assignment, not the left" why? You can have an arbitrarily-complex expression on the LHS, provided it's ultimately an array access expression. For example: `foo.bar().baz()[0] = ...`. The compiler is simply being consistent, and inserting validity checks wherever expressions of non-reifiable type are evaluated, prior to accessing fields of the expected type.

Comment: Does the compiler insert a cast in the code you supplied?  I bet it doesn't.

Comment: @markspace if `bar()` or `baz()` have non-reifiable return types and the compiler knows the type statically, yep, casts will be inserted. Try decompiling https://ideone.com/WsMKT8.

Comment: @markspace try this one too https://ideone.com/hZkZDE

Comment: Your second example is a little more cogent, but the casts for the array still seem unnecessary to me, and pernicious.  The exact same operations are fine with Object[].  The generic version doesn't actually need to be different for simple assignment.

Comment: @markspace consider an example when you have a `GenericTest<String>` and a `GenericTest<Integer>`, and _for dark and unspeakable reasons_, their `aa` is the same array instance, concretely a `Object[]`. If you don't have a runtime cast, `theStringOne.aa[0] = "";` puts a `String` into the array (you don't get an `ArrayStoreException`), then `Integer i = theIntegerOne.aa[0];` would fail with a CCE. By having a checked cast of the array expression, you avoid that potential heap pollution. (Ultimately, this all comes down to "don't ignore the compiler warning you about unchecked casts")

Comment: I'm saying the compiler should check the type of the element, not the type of the array.  `theStringOne.aa[0] = (String) "";` and `Integer i = (Integer) theIntegerOne.aa[0];`  If you do that then the type of the array can be Object[] and no harm is done.

Comment: @markspace the compiler _does_ do those (at least the second one), as well: this is why you get a CCE. The thing about heap pollution is that you might detect it long after and far away from the place where it occurred, making it really difficult to debug. It is far, far better to stop you putting the `String` into the array in the first place than to worry about it not being an `Integer` when you eventually take it out.

Comment: @markspace I just add "System.out.println(aa.getClass())" after "aa[1]=y;" in the constructor body and the program ran without problem, what do you think? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, the exception message is this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
```

It is saying that it can't cast an `Object[]` to an `Integer[]`.

The root cause of is the initializer in:

```
    T [] aa = (T[]) new Object[2];
```

That typecast is an **unsafe** typecast.  And indeed the compiler tells you that *something* is wrong:

```
$ javac GenericTest.java 
Note: GenericTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Anyhow ... what is happening is that when you then do this:

```
ll.aa[0] = 6;
```

the JVM is trying to cast the `ll.aa` to an `Integer[]` ... because that is what the static typing says that it should be.  But it isn't an `Integer[]`.  It is an `Object[]`.  Since `Object[]` is not assignment compatible with an `Integer[]` that gives you a class cast exception.

(Why is it doing a hidden type cast?  Well this is how the JVM ensures runtime type safety in the face of possible unsafe casts and the like!)

---

How to fix it?

Avoid using `T[]`.  Use `List<T>` instead.

Unfortunately, if you *have to* use `T[]` there is no easy fix.   Basically arrays of a generic type parameter are difficult to create.  You end up having to pass the `Class` object for the parameter's actual class as an extra parameter.   Something like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class GenericTest<T> {
    T [] aa;
    T bb;

    public GenericTest(Class<T> cls, T x, T y) {sy
        aa = (T[]) Array.newInstance(cls, 2);
        aa[0] = x; aa[1] = y;
        System.out.println(aa[0] + " " + aa[1]); //OK
    }

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        GenericTest<Integer> ll = new GenericTest<>(Integer.class, 1, 2);
        ll.bb = 1; // OK
        ll.aa[0] = 6; // ClassCastException from Object to Integer

    }
}
```

There is still a warning about an unsafe typecast ... but in this case it is safe to suppress the warning.

---

For Java 8 onwards, there is another solution which involves passing a reference to the array constructor for `Integer[]`; see Andy Turner's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68742688/139985).  This is cleaner than using reflection and calling `Array.newInstance`, but you still have to pass an extra parameter to the constructor.

Comment: As an addendum, if you add a method to `GenericTest` to make the same assignment with the proper types, it works fine.  So part of the problem is perhaps the Java designers don't like using non-private fields like this and didn't test their type inference fully.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error if I write `Object a1 = aa[0];` can someone explain this?

Comment: Pretty much any interaction with `aa` is going to break with a ClassCastException, Hossmeister. `Object[]` and `Integer[]` are in no way compatible with each other practically, in at the language level (because array covariance specs are broken), they somewhat are, actually, but not in the right direction.

Comment: but the line ll.bb = 1; works and ll.bb is Object type

Comment: That's fine.  The `1` is converted to an `Integer` and an `Integer` can be assigned to an `Object` ... and cast back to an `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks Stephen C, it's solve the problem, but it's incredible as JAVA is sometimes ilogical

Comment: Illogical?  No.   Unexpected / counter-intuitive? Yes. There are sound logical reasons for the design of Java ... when you consider the history of how it got to where it is today.  But there were / are some strong imperatives that mean that the overall design is not perfect.

Comment: rzwitserloot: I don't know why you say "Object[] and Integer[] are in no way compatible with each other practically". We can assign an Interger array to an Object array. So, by logique, in  aa[0] = 1;  I am assigning an integer to aa[0] with type Object. It's very confusing.....

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
ll.aa[0] = 6;
```

fails because the compiler has inserted some casts. Because it knows that `ll` is a `GenericTest<Integer>`, it expected `aa` to be an `Integer[]`.

The compiler inserts a cast to this type before you can do anything with it: it is evaluated identically to:

```
((Integer[]) ll.aa)[0] = Integer.valueOf(6);
```

The problem is that `ll.a` isn't an `Integer[]`, it's an `Object[]`, so this cast fails.

These casts are inserted even when you're doing something that could be applied to "any array", or even "any object": for example, `ll.a.toString()` would have casts inserted, even though `toString` is available on all subclasses of `Object`, i.e. all objects.

---

```
T [] aa = (T[]) new Object[2];
```

As already pointed out by StephenC, this is an *unchecked cast*. *Checked* casts are instructions inserted into the bytecode, which statically check that the object is of a particular type. But, because `T` is a type variable, there is no "particular type" that the compiler can choose to insert a `checkcast` instruction on that assignment.

The correct way to deal with this is either:

- Use a `List<T>` instead of a `T[]` as the field type. Generics and arrays don't play nicely together anyway, so you're better off sticking with generics.

  You can use a fixed-length array, e.g. `Arrays.asList(null, null)`, to mimick an array, insofar as you can only set the elements, not clear/add/remove etc.
- Inject a `T[]` (or a `Supplier<T[]>`, or an `IntFunction<T[]>` etc) into the constructor of the `GenericTest`, in order that you push the burden of ensuring the correct type onto the caller:

```
public GenericTest(T x, T y, IntFunction<T[]> arrayFn) {
  // ...
  aa = arrayFn.apply(2);  // Creates an array of the right length.
}

// Then...

GenericTest<Integer> ll = new GenericTest(1, 2, Integer[]::new);
ll.aa[0] = 6;
```

This will then be type-correct, because `aa` was created using `Integer[]::new`, i.e. it's an `Integer[]`. The casts are still inserted, they just pass the type check.

Comment: This sentence "The problem is that ll.a isn't an Integer[], it's an Object[], so this cast fails." can be applied to  "ll.bb = 1;",  the compiler insert a cast "(Integer )ll.bb = 1" but ll.bb is an Object and it can't be casted to Interger. Can you explain me the difference?. Thanks

Comment: `ll.bb = 1` isn't doing anything with the current value of `ll.bb`: it's overwriting it. It doesn't matter what its current value is, so there's no need to cast it to check if it's of a particular type. `ll.aa[0]`, otoh, is using the current value of `ll.aa`, so that needs a cast.

Comment: Also: "the compiler insert a cast "(Integer )ll.bb = 1"" no, because that's casting `ll`, not `ll.bb` - so this wouldn't compile because `Integer` has no `bb` field. Nor would `(Integer) (ll.bb) = 1`, because a cast expression isn't valid on the LHS of an [assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-Assignment).

Answer (score 3):

This is what happens when you use generics. Because generics are erased at runtime, compiler still needs to somehow be safe (after erasure) that things work correctly. Let's simplify this:

```
GenericTest<Integer> ll = new GenericTest<>(1,2);
ll.bb = 1; // OK
System.out.println(ll.aa.getClass());
```

The last line is going to be translated to:

```
    28: getfield      #7    // Field aa:[Ljava/lang/Object;
    31: checkcast     #42   // class "[Ljava/lang/Integer;"
```

notice the `checkcast`. Since your `T` was resolved as `Integer`, means that the array must be `Integer[]` too; when in reality it is `Object []`. Compiler is trying to warn you btw when you do :

```
T [] aa = (T []) new Object[2];
```

because this is unsafe. In general, generic arrays are a major headache in java, imo.

Answer (score 1):

> `T [] aa = (T[]) new Object[2];`

Because that line is broken. Your compiler warned you when you tried to compile it. As a general rule, if you get a compiler warning you do not understand, then do something else - java compiler warnings are best treated as: "Your code is completely broken and this is not going to work, but for the benefit of e.g. trying to start this application up because you want to test a completely different part of it, we'll just slap this broken stuff in a class file so you can move on, for now. Do not under any circumstances publish this to production until you fully understand this warning first."

In java, generics is a 100% compile-time show: Generics are compiler-checked documentation. At runtime, generics are mostly erased, and the few places where they remain, they are 'comments' as far as the runtime is concerned. The verifier and the runtime system **never** does any checks, **ever**. If javac allows it, the generics are now done being useful.

This in sharp contrast to arrays: Arrays are their own object and they DO know their 'component type'. Also, the compiler doesn't do all that much checking on them, but the runtime DOES. If you use some classfile hackery to put an `Integer` in a `List<String>`, the runtime will let you. However, you cannot use any amount of hackery to put an Integer in a `String[]`. It just won't work - you end up with an `ArrayStoreException` instead.

Because arrays actually know their type, at runtime, `Integer[]` and `Object[]` are different types (whereas at runtime, a `List` is just a `List` - the runtime doesn't know what generics are).

`T` is Integer, and that variable is of type `T[]`, therefore, it is `Integer[]`, therefore, any interactions with `aa` get you an implicit cast to `Integer[]`. This is 100% analogous to this code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List raw = list; // legal, but gets you a warning.
raw.add(5);
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

You can compile it. If you run it, the **last** line throws ClassCastException which is weird, there is no cast there at all! Ah, but there is. Because the compiler rewrote that for you, into this code (and remember, the runtime **does not know generics**, which is why it is rewritten like this):

```
List list = new ArrayList();
List raw = list;
raw.add(Integer.valueOf(5));
String $v = (String) list.get(0);
System.out.println($v);
```

You'd think: Wait, why cast it? There is a `System.out.println(Object)` variant? But, that's just the rules. Java will immediately cast that because it can, after all, `list` is a `List<String>` which means its `get(int idx)` method can be assumed to always return strings, so java will cast it as soon as possible even if not needed.

The exact same thing happens in your code: It sees `T[]`, where T is bound to `Integer`, so, `aa` is cast to `Integer[]` even if it wasn't needed. This cast fails at runtime because an object created as `new Object[2]` is clearly not an `Integer[]`. After all, I can invoke:

```
Integer[] x = ...;
System.out.println(x.getClass().getComponentType());
```

and this code is guaranteed to print `java.lang.Integer`. If I can write code so that `java.lang.Object` is printed, that would be broken, and yet that is exactly what would happen.

### So how do I fix it?

Do not, ever, write `T[]`. It's as simple as that.

Arrays are low-level constructs you shouldn't be using, especially if the component type is non-primitive. If you MUST use them, then they should be relegated to internal implementation details, hidden behind a nicer API.

Do the casting in those wrappers.

This is *precisely* how ArrayList works. ArrayList has an array inside that holds your list elements (hence the name ArrayList). That is defined as `Object[] storage = new Object[...];`. Not `T[] storage = (T[]) new Object[..]`. Then, the get method of ArrayList does the casting:

```
public T get(int idx) {
     // check if idx is within 0-size()...
    return (T) storage[idx];
}
```

This cast does nothing (javac emits a warning that it has no idea what T might be and the runtime doesn't either, so nobody can check this), but this will all work at runtime (obviously: ArrayList works fine).

You need to do the same thing, and hide that array, if you must use it. Or better yet, don't do any of this stuff and use `List<T>` instead. Arrays of non-primitive types are a blight: If you use them, you better have an excellent reason for it, and hide it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This code works (printing the class inside the constructor....) and I don't know why

```
public class GenericTest<AnyType> {
    public AnyType [] aa = (AnyType []) new Object[2];
    public AnyType bb;
    public GenericTest(AnyType x, AnyType y) {
        aa[0]=x; aa[1]=y; System.out.println(aa.getClass());
        System.out.println( aa[0]+" "+aa[1]); //OK
    }
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        GenericTest<Integer> ll = new GenericTest<>(1,2);
        ll.aa[0]= 6; // ClassCastException from Object to Integer
    }
 }
```

Comment: It works because there is no cast which can be statically inserted into the constructor to cause it to fail. The type of `aa[0]` is `AnyType`, a type variable bounded by `Object`: the only cast which _could_ be inserted there statically is `(Object)`, which will always succeed.